# keystroke capturing. ctrl makes KeyChar attribute empty

Tags: java

I have a piece of code that allows me to capture keystroke and print them with a System.out.println. My problem is that when I try to use it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>) it removes the KeyChar attribute of the <kbd>m</kbd> key. Does anyone know why this happen and how I can solve it?

```
       public TestForm() {
        initComponents();
KeyEventDispatcher keyEventDispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(final KeyEvent e) 
  {
    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.isAltDown())
        {
         System.out.println("ALT + "+e.getKeyChar());   
        }
    else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.isShiftDown())
        {
            System.out.println("SHIFT + "+e.getKeyChar());
        }
    else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.isControlDown())
        {
             System.out.println("CTRL + "+e.getKeyChar()/*+"\n"+e*/);
        }   
    else
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
            return      true;   
        }
  };


KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(keyEventDispatcher)

;        
}
```

I'm quite new to java so it might be something simple im missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is an important difference between key code and key char.  A key code represents a key on a keyboard.  A key char represents a letter in some alphabet.  There is a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key on your keyboard but there is no letter in any alphabet (e.g. no unicode character) for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.  So when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed you get a KEY_PRESSED event with a key code but no key char.

Not all hope is lost though.  It looks like you are trying to detect when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and some character is pressed (e.g. if I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead of just <kbd>A</kbd>).  The problem is that you are looking at KEY_PRESSED events.  In Java there is an important distinction between the KEY_PRESSED event and the KEY_TYPED event.

For exmaple, if I were to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on my keyboard I would first press down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, then press down the <kbd>A</kbd> key, then release them more or less at the same time.  In my mind I think of this as one action, but it's not.  What happens in Java is you get:

```
KEY_PRESSED (keyCode = VK_CTRL, keyChar = CHAR_UNDEFINED) //I press down Ctrl key
KEY_PRESSED (keyCode = VK_A, keyChar = CHAR_UNDEFINED) //I press down the a key
KEY_TYPED (keyCode = VK_UNDEFINED, keyChar = 'A') //The 'typing' of the letter 'A'
//some key released events that are not relevant to this discussion
```

As you can see, a KEY_PRESSED event has a key code but no key char (this is fired when a key on the keyboard is pressed down).  A KEY_TYPED event has a key char but not key code (this represents the completion of a key sequence resulting in a letter).

All of this is documented in detail on the javadocs for the [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) page.